# Why do the weights file size increase after resuming training in Keras？

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I trained a model ,which output the h5 weights file with size of 11.5M. But after I resume training with the weights file and the same model, the output size of weights file increased to 17.2M.

Do somebody know about this ?

Comment: Could you provide a code you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko.I found the problem, which is that I changed the optimizer      in resuming training.So, I guess that the weights file not only stores  the weights of net architecture, but also some training information.